# image path not working when accessing php include file from two different folders

Tags: php

I have included a 'header' file in files which are in root folder and the header file is in 'inc' folder.
header.php is completely working when accessing from subdomain/main-website/index.php file.
But when accessing from subdomain/index.php, only the logo is not showing due to the relative path.

Folder Structure:
subdomain/main-website

- css
- img
- inc (header.php inside inc folder)
- index.php (`<?php include_once 'inc/header.php'?>`)
- about.php (`<?php include_once 'inc/header.php'?>`)

subdomain

- main-website
- index.php (`<?php include_once 'main-website/inc/header.php'?>`)

header.php

```
<div>
 <img class="logoImg" src="img/logo.png" alt="" title="" />
</div>

<nav id="nav-menu-container">
 <ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="menu-active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

So what should be done or what is the best approach for this.

Comment: `src="/main-website/img/logo.png"` relative to site root

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path for the image `https://your.subdomain.com/main-website/img/logo.png`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can always anchor yourself on the **root** folder by using **../path-to-sub-folder/**. Accordingly, you must then give the folder names starting from this root - base excluded. This should work as long as base directory carries all your sub-domains. But as a last resort, and **NOT for public-facing links**, you can refer to absolute file reference like **/var/www/html/base_folder/sub_folder/**.